# Webkit and IE - AJAX form submition to docs.google.com error

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, webkit, xmlhttprequest

Despite the fact that there are lots of questions in stackoverflow related to XMLHttpRequest and same-origin-policy error, I didn't find solution for my issue. Even though the [The same origin policy wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) gives a great reference to the related subject, I wasn't able to find proper way.

The issue is that WebKit based browsers and IE raise bellow issue when I try to submit form data to google forms. However, the mentioned browsers successfully submit the data and I have it in my spreadsheet.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/a/<myDomain>/forms/d/<myFormKey>/formResponse. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

On the other hand FireFox does the job and returns status code: `200 OK`. The question is how can I solve the issue, that WebKit based browsers and IE show status code `0 OK` or `200 OK`?

here is the code that I am using

**HTML:**

```
<form name="quickMessageForm" submit="postQuickMessageToGoogle()" >
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
  <textarea name="content" id="content"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.postQuickMessageToGoogle = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://docs.google.com/a/<myDomain>/forms/d/<myFormKey>/formResponse',
    data: {
      'entry.397424023'   : $scope.quickMessage.name,
      'entry.1127838473'  : $scope.quickMessage.email,
      'entry.1078099467'  : $scope.quickMessage.content
    },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'xml',
    statusCode: {
      0: function (){
        successSubmit(
          $scope.quickMessage.name,
          $scope.quickMessage.email,
          $scope.quickMessage.content
        );
      },
      200: function (){
        successSubmit(
          $scope.quickMessage.name,
          $scope.quickMessage.email,
          $scope.quickMessage.content
        );
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved it following iShow's comment on this [post](https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000#comment-1645894327).
the problem seemed in the `dataType: 'xml'`. When I changed it to the `dataType: 'jsonp'` the problem was solved.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. It works, but now I am having response execution error: `Refused to execute script from 'https://docs.google.com/a/<myDomain>/forms/d/<myFormKey>/formResponse...aksad&entry.1127838473=max%40don.com&entry.1078099467=dfgh&_=1416653018839' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`